# Calling outbound-gateway with dynamic parameters.

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="requestChannel"
    expression="''">
    <int:poller cron="0 0/2 * * * ?"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="requestConcactChannel">
    <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true">
        <int:header name="Accept" value="application/json" />
        <int:header name="OData-MaxVersion" value="4.0" />
        <int:header name="OData-Version" value="4.0" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="#{requestbl.geturl()}"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" http-method="GET"
        header-mapper="headerMapper" >
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    <int:service-activator ref="accountResponseHandler" />
</int:chain>
```

Following this the code which I'm using to send request on some Urls through outbound-gateway. I have to generate this url dynamically.

requestbl.geturl() returns me the Url value but it is called only once when application was loaded. I want to load it every time when the request is send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative for you:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="url-expression" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                <![CDATA[
SpEL Expression resolving to a URL to which the requests should be sent. The resolved
value may include {placeholders} for further evaluation against uri-variables.
                ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

This is called at runtime against each `requestMessage` and also you can call any bean from that expression.

So, your use-case would be like this:

```
url-expression="@requestbl.geturl()"
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.